# Visual studio 2010 and asp.net mvc3, adding new project into existing

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2010, asp.net-mvc-3

I have situation like this: I am doing my own mvc project in visual studio and i found example of simmilar project on the web, in solution explorer i see that it's actaully 4 projects inside 1 as you can see in picture:[image]

So my question is how to add for example Northwind:Model to my own project, as you can see Northwind:model contains Properities, References and classes. Most important to me are classes.
[Edit]my question is about type of project to add, that is confusing me.
Also i will need all 3 Northwind.Model, Repositories and Respositories.Entity.

Thanks for answers!

Comment: Could it be that you actually want to know how you can `reference` Classes from Northwind.Model library?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply right click on the Solution (Grid in your case) and select **Add > New Project...**.

This will take you to the standard New Project dialog which you just use as normal. It can be any type of project you like, but in this case you probably want a class library.

If you've got an existing project you want to include then you can do this in a similar way. You don't have to copy the source into the same directory structure but it can help. Make sure it sits under the Grid folder. Then right click on the solution and select **Add > Existing Project...***. Browse to the folder containing the project and select the .csproj file.

Comment: My consider which type it is? class library or?

Comment: @GoranB - it can be any type you like, but in this case you probably want a class library.

Comment: @ChrisF It sounds to me like OP rather wants to add an existing project to his existing solution.

Comment: @Filburt - ah, yes it looks like that might be the case.

Comment: Big thanks to ChrisF and it is a library class, i have tried it, and i don't want to use xisting project to add in mine.

Comment: @ChrisF I tried to Add a solution to my ASP.net web app. but I couldn't do it. There is no "New Project" under Add option. All the options I can see when I click Add is "new Item", "Existing Item"... "Module", "class" Do I have to change any settings of VS2010 to see this option???

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want to reference projects Northwind.Model, Northwind.Repositories and Northwind.Repositories.Entity so you can use classes in your project jqGrid.

In that case right-click **References** in your jqGrid project, choose **Add Reference...** and switch to tab **Projects**.

Here you should see all available projects in your solution. Select the projects you like to reference and click **OK**.